# Match value according to three patteren

Tags: jquery, regex

want to match value of textbox with three different pattren. If Exact match Found then return true else Empty TextBox.

```
HTML:

    <input type="text" id="txtRegNo" class="txtRegNo" />

Pattren: DL-01-T-7405
         DL-01-TT-7405
         DL-01-TTT-7405
```

what i done so far

```
objvalue=$(this.id).val();

if(objvalue==?)
{
return true;
}
else
{
$(this.id).val('');
return false;
}
```

How can i match my value According to one of these three Pattren,if it is among any of these three pattren then success else error Condition

Comment: Please show the html also

Comment: Maybe this: `if(objvalue.match(/pattern1|pattern2|pattern3/)) {//success`

Comment: Selector seems to be incorrect, as id should have to be denoted with a `#` and class should be with `.`

Comment: i have question regarding wants to match Value with three Patterns

Answer (score 0):

try this demo:

```js
$('#txtRegNo').on('change', function(){
 var objvalue = $(this).val();
 if(objvalue.match(/^DL-01-[T]{1,3}-7405$/) !== null) {
     console.log('SUCCESS: ' + objvalue);
    } else {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + objvalue);
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtRegNo" class="txtRegNo" />
<i>Press `ENTER` key after inputting</i>
```